# Evento "onclick" dentro de variable y Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

Tags: javascript, html

Mi idea es agregar filas a una tabla con un evento "onclick" en ellas.Como veis,en "var tabla" creo los "tr,td" y le paso los styles. Hasta aquí, sin problema, pero cuando lo lanzo me da un error del tipo "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }"

Parece ser que todo es cosa de la forma en la que añado el "onclick" a "tabla", porque pasándole valores a mano a insertarLinkPrefijo(prefijoFinal) funciona y "recogerPrefijos" me pinta todas las filas de la tabla bien;únicamente falla cuando hago click en cualquiera de las filas dándome el error antes mencionado.Los valores "revisión,revisión2 y revisión3" son strings,así que no creo que sea ese el problema.

HTML:

```
 <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="container">
                        <h2>Filtro de Prefijos</h2>
                        <p>Escriba en el campo "Buscar" para realizar un filtrado de opciones</p>
                        <input class="form-control" id="myInputPrefix" type="text" placeholder="Buscar..">
                        <br>
                        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Resultados</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody id="myTablePrefix">

                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Tengo las siguientes funciones:

```
  function recogerPrefijos(revision, revision2, revision3) {
        var prefijoFinal = "PREFIX" + revision + ":" + revision2;
        prefijoFinal = prefijoFinal.toString();
        var tabla = "<tr><td style=\"max-width:50px; padding:10px;\"><a class=\"list-group-item list-group-item-action primary-color\" id=\"list-home-list\" data-toggle=\"list\" href=\"#list-home\" role=\"tab\" aria-controls=\"home\" title=\"Select\" data-dismiss=\"modal\" href=\"#\" onclick=\"insertarLinkPrefijo(\" + prefijoFinal + \")\">" + revision + ": " + revision2 + "</a></td></tr>";
        var table = document.getElementById("myTablePrefix");
        var row = table.insertRow(contadorRecogerPrefijos);
        row.innerHTML = tabla;
        contadorRecogerPrefijos++;

        return prefijoFinal;
    }


function insertarLinkPrefijo(prefijoFinal) {
        var sentencia = prefijoFinal;
        var editor = document.getElementsByClassName("CodeMirror-line");
        editor[0].textContent = sentencia;
    }
```

Muchas gracias

Comment: Hola Jonan, nos ayudarías mucho creando un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Complementando el comentario de @kacospro favor agrega el HTML

Comment: El problema los son las " esto es lo que estás haciendo... " onclick="insertarLinkPrefijo("prefijoFinal")" cambialo. Y además prefijo final no se está sustituyendo como esperas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me faltarian datos para contestarte con total certeza, pero quizás es que tienes mal codificado todo el string que va en la tabla con el onclick. Aqui te dejo la corrección.

```
var tabla = "<tr><td style=\"max-width:50px; padding:10px;\"><a class=\"list-group-item list-group-item-action primary-color\" id=\"list-home-list\" data-toggle=\"list\" href=\"#list-home\" role=\"tab\" aria-controls=\"home\" title=\"Select\" data-dismiss=\"modal\" href=\"#\" onclick=\"insertarLinkPrefijo('" + prefijoFinal + "')\">" + revision + ": " + revision2 + "</a></td></tr>";
```

Comment: Eso es lo que se le ha dicho en el comentario.

Comment: Gracias,ya funciona.Eran las dichosas comillas